# An error with flask-sqlalchemy (in creating a db)

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have been trying to organize my file structure in my flask app (the current structure is):

```
├───.git
├───.vscode
├───env
├───src
├─── __init__.py
├─── site.db
│   ├───main
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └─── routes.py
│   │   └─── __init__.py
│   ├───posts
│   │   └───__pycache__
│   │   └─── routes.py
│   │   └─── __init__.py
│   │   └─── forms.py
│   │   └─── utils.py
│   ├───static
│   │   ├───css
│   │   ├───js
│   │   └───profile_pics
│   ├───templates
│   │   └─── ...
│   ├───users
│   │   └─── routes.py
│   │   └─── __init__.py
│   │   └─── forms.py
│   │   └─── utils.py
├───run.py
```

The `site.db` file for some reason is empty **even though** my `__init__.py` file has "db.create_all()"...

Although, I *am* getting this error when I try and request the index.html page

```py
[2020-07-16 11:54:38,819] ERROR in app: Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: post

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", 
line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\OneDrive\code\CloneBook\src\main\routes.py", line 13, in home
    posts = Post.query.order_by(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 496, in paginate
    items = self.limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3341, in all
    return list(self)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3503, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3528, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1014, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1127, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1317, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1511, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 178, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1277, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 593, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: post
[SQL: SELECT post.id AS post_id, post.title AS post_title, post.date_posted AS post_date_posted, post.content AS post_content, post.user_id AS post_user_id
FROM post ORDER BY post.date_posted DESC
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is most likely doing the `db.create_all()` *before* models have been imported (from whatever file they're in, since you don't have any `models.py` files). Importing models has the side-effect of registering them.

Comment: Right, I updated my code to:
```python

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'
login_manager.login_message_category = 'info'
mail = Mail(app)


def create_app(config_class=Config):
    """Create the app."""
    from src import models

    from src.users.routes import users
    from src.posts.routes import posts
    from src.main.routes import main

    db.create_all()

    app.register_blueprint(users)
    app.register_blueprint(posts)
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app

```